# Aborting scriptreplay messes up my terminal. How to undo and potentially prevent?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, recording

I recorded a long running command with the `script` command and wanted to have replayed with `scriptreplay`. After I saw what I wanted to see I aborted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (aka `SIGINT`) and now line breaks and similar things are severely messed up:

```
$ script --help

Usage:
       script [options] [file]

                              Make a typescript of a terminal session.

                                                                      Options:
                                                                               -I, --log-in <file>           log stdin to file
                                                                                                                               -O, --log-out <file>          log stdout to file (default)
                                                                                                                                                                                          -B, --log-io <file>           log stdin and stdout to file

         -T, --log-timing <file>       log timing information to file
                                                                      -t[<file>], --timing[=<file>] deprecated alias to -T (default file is stderr)
                                                                                                                                                    -m, --logging-format <name>   force to 'classic' or 'advanced' format

                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -a, --append                  append to the log file
                                   -c, --command <command>       run command rather than interactive shell
                                                                                                           -e, --return                  return exit code of the child process
                                                                                                                                                                               -f, --flush                   run flush after each write
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            --force                   use output file even when it is a link
                                                                 -E, --echo <when>             echo input in session (auto, always or never)
                                                                                                                                             -o, --output-limit <size>     terminate if output files exceed size
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -q, --quiet                   be quiet

            -h, --help                    display this help
                                                            -V, --version                 display version

                                                                                                         For more details see script(1).
                                                                                                                                        %
```

I ran the command like this: `script -B command.log -T command.log.time -eq -c "command"` and then replayed it like this `scriptreplay -t command.log.time -B command.log -d 2`

So how can I fix this? And how can I cleanly end a `scriptreplay` session without this happening in the first place?

Comment: Does `reset` work? Caution, it will eat your scrollback.

Comment: `reset` does work indeed! Didn't know this command. Any idea how to prevent this happening in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because script tries to replay the session *very faithfully*, including moving the cursor and changing various terminal internals. If you were to disable the faithful recreation (not sure if that's supported), its output would look broken.

Instead, you can wrap scriptreplay in a shell script that restores the terminal to a known-good state:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_restore () {
    trap SIGINT
    reset -I
    exit
}
trap _restore INT

scriptreplay "$@"
```

and place this script at (e.g.) `~/.local/bin/scriptreplay-fixed`, adding it to the path if it's missing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `trap _restore SIGINT`?

Comment: I turned into an override for the `scriptreplay` command: https://gist.github.com/BrainStone/b682ef922bc3d92294e01d8b2220f5a0 but same idea